# Unable import a package which was added through maven

Tags: java, maven

I need to add a third party jar into my project which is using maven for dependency management.

since the third party jar is not available in maven-central, i have installed it into my local .m2 respository using following command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ThirdPartyApp.jar -DgroupId=com.thirdpartydomain -DartifactId=ThirdPartyApp -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and added it into my project using following dependency snippet

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.thirdpartydomain</groupId>
  <artifactId>ThirdPartyApp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and my project build is successful (by using mvn clean package)

but when i am trying to import it, it is failing

```
import com.thirdpartydomain.*;
```

The import **com.thirdpartydomain** can't be resolved

Comment: Is the snippet you provided within the `dependencyManagement`-block?

Comment: it is inside ```<dependencies>...</dependencies>```

Comment: Yes. But is this block surrounded by the `depencendyManagement`-block?

Comment: No, it is not. this is the structure ```<project>...<dependencies>...</dependencies>...</project>```

Answer (score 0):

the package name is not **necessarily** the same as the group id. Also, please regenerate the project settings and class path if you work with some IDE such as Eclipse or IDEA.

Comment: Since OP installed the jar manually, OP defined the group- and artifact-id.

Comment: project is not building from the command line too, with ```mvn clean package```